# Search result of News using SOLR Search giving http://{plugin.tx_news.settings.detailpid}/ instead of real URL in Typo3

Tags: solr, typo3, tx-news

I'm using TYPO3 7.6.10 and solr 6.5.0

Plugin: Apache solr for TYPO3 6.1.0

The search is working fine. I indexed Pages and News but when I get result of news it gives `http://{plugin.tx_news.settings.detailpid}/` in URL instead of real URL.

I gave `plugin.tx_news.settings.detailPid = 1130` in Constants of TYPOSCRIPT.

Please open below link and check the second result

http://www.fujifilm-mea.com/searchresult-page/?q=A+free+firmware+update+to+enhance+the+performance+of+the+FUJIFILM+X-Pro2+is+now+available+for+download&id=1263&L=0

Comment: Did you clear cache and reindex after setting the constant?

Comment: Yes @GeorgRinger

Comment: @JasvinderSingh Did you find the problem - for me all links also die

Answer (score 1):

What is configured in plugin.tx_solr.index.queue.news.fields.url?

At least there seems to be a diffrence in the casing (detailpid <=> detailPid)

plugin.tx_news.settings.detailpid
plugin.tx_news.settings.detailPid

Comment: casing could be adapted as it is interpreted as domain, which is caseinsensitive and used in lower chars in most cases.

Comment: I think I have not set `plugin.tx_solr.index.queue.news.fields.url`. Where to set it? Please help

Comment: if you have ext:solr installed, you can add "Search - Index Queue Configuration for news (solr) [EXT:solr/Configuration/TypoScript/Examples/IndexQueueNews/]" in template includes.

Comment: I have the same probleme, any solution for that please ? @mtness : I tried this but not help

Answer (score 0):

**in your root Setup:**

```
plugin.tx_solr.index.queue {
news = 1
news {
    table = tx_news_domain_model_news
    fields {
        abstract = teaser
        author = author
        authorEmail_stringS = author_email
        title = title
        content = SOLR_CONTENT
        content {
            cObject = COA
            cObject {
                10 = TEXT
                10 {
                    field = bodytext
                    noTrimWrap = || |
                }
            }
        }

        url = TEXT
        url {
            typolink.parameter = {$plugin.tx_news.settings.detailPid}
            typolink.additionalParams = &tx_news_pi1[controller]=News&tx_news_pi1[action]=detail&tx_news_pi1[news]={field:uid}&L={field:__solr_index_language}
            typolink.additionalParams.insertData = 1
            typolink.useCacheHash = 1
            typolink.returnLast = url
        }
    }
    attachments {
        fields = related_files
    }
}
```

}

**in root Constants:**

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.detailPid = 3   //change "3" with ID of your NewsSingle Page
```

Clear all cache and Initialize Solr connections and re-index News again

Answer (score 0):

The problem was for me in an old index. When correct pageUid added in constans.typoscript - need reindex news and all works

Answer (score -1):

This is not a valid TypoScript constant:
{plugin.tx_news.settings.detailpid}

Please check your TypoScript Setup and change that to:
{$plugin.tx_news.settings.detailpid}

https://wiki.typo3.org/TypoScript_Constants